# Adding "bot" credentials to jenkins when using Unix user/group database

Tags: jenkins, authorization, jenkins-plugins

We're using Jenkins server (v. 1.571) with the following authorization configuration:

1. Security Realm: Unix user/group database.
2. Authorization: Matrix-based security

up until now, each member of our team used its private credentials to login and perform operations on this server.

We want to enable bot scripts to login to the server with "global" credentials and perform some of these operations, without changing the current credentials of the users (and hopefully, don't touch the current authorization guidelines).

How can this be achieved?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin). It provides you the option to define user and password in `Manage Hudson > Configure System` section. To add to it, as the name suggests, the password will be masked in the console output. Even in the *Configure* section where you create user and password, the password will remain in masked state.

Comment: Hi @Technext, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure that's what I need, as all I wish is to **login** to jenkins with these credentials. As I see it, this plugin is relevant to specific jobs..

Comment: I see. If you're using Unix user/group database, is it not possible for you to create one user with the same name and password as that of the bot in your system and use the same for authentication?

Comment: I'm afraid not, as I'm not the Admin of this group (we cannot create "generic" users for that purpose). That would have been certainly easier.